# Chrome Extension - manifest.json load all js in folder

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension, wich will run some tests and I need to be able to change those tests by adding a new js file for each test inside the folder tests, so I tried to use this on my manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://mysite.com/*"],
      "js": [
        "content.js",
        "tests/*.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
```

But chrome throws an error when uploading this manifest. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The [API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) specifies that only an array of strings can be used. So I don't think the glob pattern will work here.

Comment: what is the error chrome throws?

Comment: I didn't bother writing there because it's a simple error: "Could not load javascript for content script".

Comment: Try to use something like browserify or webpack. Then include your bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't do that, you need to explicitly list all the scripts.

Your best bet is to have some sort of build script that updates the `manifest.json` itself, or combines scripts into a bigger one you can explicitly include.